# I can't access my ETH wallet (made on wallet.ethereum.org in 2017)

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, mist, myetherwallet, ethereum-classic

In 2017, when I first started to mine, I made a wallet in wallet.ethereum.org (I stopped briefly after, so I have around 2.2 ETH in that wallet).

Now in 2021 I tried to go to wallet.ethereum.org but the website seems to be down... and according to some instructions I have to transfer it to MEW using JSON or Keystore, which I don't have them anymore..

The only thing I have is the public address, a username and a password,(key icon) address 0x.........

Is there anything I can do with this to access to my ETH address and transfer my 2.2 eth?

Is there someone that can guide me through this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In this deprecation notice they mention where to look for the keystore file https://wolovim.medium.com/mist-migration-patterns-6bcf066ac383.

Answer (score 1):

If you were mining, I assume that you were running your own node.

In that case, your keystore file should be located in a hidden .ethereum folder here on linux - `~/.ethereum/keystore`

If you still have the keystore file for your account in that folder, you should be able to decrypt it using your password. I suggest you use [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/access-my-wallet) to do so. You will then be able to transfer eth from MyEtherWallet.

Comment: I did it on windows.

What if i don't have the keystore anymore is there a way to access it?

Comment: On Windows, the path to the folder should be ~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum. If you have completely lost your kestore file, I don't think that you can access your account anymore. The keystore file is your encrypted private key.